# Show $\limsup_{x\to \infty} \sin\left((x+t)^2\right)-\sin\left(x^2\right)=2$ for $ t \ne 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

[My messing around on desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fcqigitwel) strongly suggests to me that this is true, yet I have been been unable to prove it. I have tried to explicitly find a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\lim x_n =\infty$ and $ \lim \sin\left((x_n+t)^2\right)-\sin\left(x_n^2\right) = 2$ without success. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we write

$$\sin((x+t)^2) - \sin(x^2) = 2 \cos(x^2 + tx + (t^2/2)) \sin(tx + (t^2/2)).$$

So we need $x$ such that $x^2 + tx + (t^2/2)$ is close to an integer multiple of $2\pi,$ and $tx + (t^2/2)$ is close to an integer multiple of $2\pi,$ plus $\pi/2.$

Let $x_k = \sqrt{2\pi k - \pi/2}$. By Fejér's theorem, the sequence $y_k = tx_k + t^2/2$ is equidistributed $\mod 2\pi$ (see for instance [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107195/references-for-the-result-that-sqrtn-is-equidistributed-mod-1)), so there is a subsequence that gets arbitrarily close to $\pi/2 \mod 2\pi$. For that subsequence $\{x_{k_i}\}_{i \ge 0}$, we have that $x_{k_i}^2 + tx_{k_i} + t^2/2 = 2\pi k_i - \pi/2 + tx_{k_i} + t^2/2$ gets arbitrarily close to $0$ $\mod 2 \pi$. This concludes the claim.